# Lookup dialog must return records related to the junction object

Tags: lookup, configuration, lookup-filter

In my requirement I have a junction object between Account and Contact. Now there is a requirement that on the case object, where standard lookup field of contact and account are present, when I have populated a contact in the field and click on the lookup icon of the account field, the lookup dialog should show all the accounts that are related to that contact via the junction object. How do I achieve this? LEt me demonstrate using an example:

For eg. There is a contact 'Contact1' which is related to 'Account1', 'Account3' and 'Account4' via the junction object records. On the case object, in the contact lookup, I selected 'COntact1'. Now when I go the account lookup and click on that magnifying glass, the dialog that opens should show only 'Accouont1','Account3' and 'Account4' in the results.

Kindly help guys. I'm stuck!

Comment: What do you have the look-up to from your Case layout? By default, the lookup would be to `Contact.accountId`, not to the link to your junction object. You'll need to change your case page layout to look-up to your junction object. Have you done that?

Comment: Yes by default it is looking up to the Contact.accountId. But I want it to show the accounts on the junction object records. What do I need to change in my case page layout?

Answer (score 1):

I'd expect you to have a look-up field on contact to the Junction object. That's what you'd want to link to. That link should give you the search menu for accounts.

Comment: The junction object obviously has the lookup o contact but not vice versa.